# Chrome version 89 on Windows 7 32-bit running out of memory

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 32-bit

Previous version was working just fine. This version gobbling memory around 1Gb and snapping.

Is there a setting that can be changed or must I downgrade?

Comment: tbh, you must upgrade - to Windows 10 & while you're at it, switch to 64-bit [which can use more RAM even if it has to use swap to do it].

Comment: @Tetsujin yes.. that is Plan A.. Plan B is to downgrade.. But need workaround fast :)

Comment: Plan C is to quit all other processes, but on 32-bit you're very RAM-limited anyway.

Comment: How much memory in total do you have?

Comment: @Moab 4GB of memory

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/m0kfj6/help_chrome_version_89_on_windows_7_32_bit_has/